# how to save the scroll state

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to save/determine the scroll state(current position) so when the user comes back to the previous site he can continue his work from the position where he left it.

Can I continuously save the scroll position to the global variable and read it when user comes back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using javascript, you can find out the scroll height then set that into a cookie.  Not a great way to do it, but it's possible.

finding the scroll height:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        console.log(scrolled);
    });
});
```

I would suggest using the jquery cookie plugin to set it into a cookie or session:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie
http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

then add the variable to the cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $.removeCookie("mySiteScrolled");
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        $.cookie("mySiteScrolled", scrolled);
        console.log(scrolled);
    });
});
```

Then add the "Check for scrolled" statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrolled = $.cookie("mySiteScrolled");
    if(scrolled){
        $(window).scrollTop(scrolled);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $.removeCookie("mySiteScrolled");
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        $.cookie("mySiteScrolled", scrolled);
        console.log(scrolled);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your code...however I have included this code in my script and I have included jquery cookie script and it is not working. nothing is happening, shouldn't your code save the current scroll state and restore it when I come back to previous site

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Have you tested any part of the code?  Are there errors?  Have you checked to see if you is at least a cookie being made?  What have you tried?

Comment: @user123_456 Wanted to tag you on this so you got an alert.

Comment: okay I have tracked the problem. When I scroll on the main site everything is okay ( cookie value is saved ) but when I click on a link I got redirected and cookie value is set on the `0` because page is starting from the top. how to save the values only for this particular site? or disable cookie saving when user click on anything that got him redirected?

Comment: or can I scroll to the certain `id`? that could be even better? to save clicked `id` in the cookie and read it

Comment: @user123_456 It seems that you will have to save a cookie variable for each page you are trying to save.   My advice is to give the body an ID and get that id name on scroll. You can either add that to the cookie or make it a new one. You can scroll to an id as well. Just grab the Id closest to the scrolltop and save that variable.  Let me know if you need help with that

Comment: @user123_456 Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vFWyC/  That should get you started.  I've made it so when you click on a box (or any element you want) it will get its top position.  You can save that top position into the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use jQuery to easily determine the scoll position `$(document).scrollTop();` and use local storage to set/get the position.